# Apples GameCenter a requirement

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center, modalviewcontroller

I'm creating an iOS game which will require the player to have a Game Center account, so when they first play they need to sign into Game Center (if not already signed in), what I'm confused about is there's obviously a cancel button in the GameCenter sign-in ViewController, how can I disable that? or display some msg when it's tapped on?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot disable that, but you can just not show any content until the user is logged in.

Comment: My game relies upon the players Game Center details to setup a Parse user account, so I need the Game Center details when they first play, but I'm not sure what to do if they tap that cancel button.

Comment: What about a message asking then to log in again and a retry button?

Comment: No, but you can detect that the user is not logged in with [[GKPlayer localPlayer] isAuthenticated]

Comment: That's what I do, I detect if the player is signed in or not and if not display the GC dialogue, but then if they tap cancel, then what? if I can't detect the cancel has been tapped how will I know to put the msg on the screen telling them to sign in again?

Comment: Just put that message by default, if they are not logged in, they will see it and they can retry

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable the cancel button, but you can check if the player was logged in successfully with

```
[localPlayer setAuthenticateHandler:^(UIViewController *login, NSError *) {
    if (localPlayer.authenticated) {
        NSLog(@"GameCenter authenticated");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"GameCenter didn't authenticate");
    }
}];
```

Comment: That's what I do, I detect if the player is signed in or not and if not display the GC dialogue, but then if they tap cancel, then what? if I can't detect the cancel has been tapped how will I know to put the msg on the screen telling them to sign in again?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you would show some sort of splash view with a "Login to Game Center" button and perhaps some explanation of your game and/or why users need to sign in to play.  Pressing the Login button would present the GameCenter login view, and if the user cancels, they will simply remain at the splash view until they tap the login button again and successfully sign in.